# ASP.Net Ajax $common.parseUnit function

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Im trying to adapt some code that I have found online that uses this function..

```
$common.parseUnit
```

Does anyone know where it lives as at present I am getting an "$common.parseUnit is undefined" error when the code hits that line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$common.parseUnit()` is exposed by the common scripts of the [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/), so you probably need to install that toolkit.

**EDIT:** If you have the toolkit installed, check if you have properly referenced the common toolkit scripts, either by decorating your extender classes with:

```
[RequiredScript(typeof(CommonToolkitScripts))]
```

Or by explicitly adding the reference to your `ToolkitScriptManager`:

```
yourToolkitScriptManager.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("Common.Common.js",
    "AjaxControlToolkit"));
```

Comment: I'm referencing the DLL, also I can see that scripts are getting loaded into the page. So not sure why it cant find it. Is there an equivalent JQuery function? Or another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @RemotecUk, maybe it's a script reference problem. See my updated answer.